# Pwn Plug like tunneling suite

Tags: ssh, tunneling

Is there some sort of a (free) SSH tunneling suite like the one on the Pwnie Express' Pwn Plug (R2)?

It has SSH over HTTP, DNS, ICMP, and other covert tunneling options and uses BackTrack 5 as a SSH revceiver.

I would like the be able to test what kind of tunneling a network is vulnerable for on a Raspberry Pi instead of the (rather expensive) Pwn Plug. In fact, all I need to know is if the tunnel is established.

**EDIT**: I think I'll just generate reverse Linux shells with metasploit on the Raspberry Pi and execute them with a script and handle the incoming connections with several multihandlers.

If someone has a better idea, please let me know